# C# Como empaquetar dlls en un .exe

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Tengo un ejecutable (.exe) desarrollado en Visual Studio 2017, lo compilo con Costura.Fody para empaquetar todas las dll que se necesitan durante la ejecución del aplicativo, sin embargo hay 3 dll que se deben copiar manualmente a la misma ubicación del aplicativo porque sino se generan excepciones en tiempo de ejecución. Las dll son:

1. SQLite.Interop.dll
2. Una dll que desarrollé yo para llamar las funciones de un sdk
3. la dll correspondiente a la base de datos de SQLite

Mis preguntas son:

1. ¿Por qué si las 3 dll se mandan a empaquetar con Costura.Fody igual hay que copiarlas manualmente?
2. Hay alguna manera de incluir las 3 dll en el .exe a parte de Costura.Fody?

Comment: Si no quieres utilizar ese compilador te dejo un link de como hacerlo pero es mas complicado. https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/233581-one-big-exe-file-with-all-the-dlls-in-net

Answer (score 0):

No conozco ese compilador, pero puedes probar a seleccionar desde Visual Studio en Referencias del proyecto, la dll que quieres copiar y dale F4, te saldrá el menú de opciones y una de ellas es "Copiar a Local", ponlo a True a ver si te ayuda.

Comment: Gracias, pero en ese caso la dll no se empaqueta sino que se copia a la misma ruta que el exe, necesito es tener el exe con todas sus dependencias incrustadas.